# Compiler chosing prefix ++ when postfix is missing - who says?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When you define a prefix operator++ for your user defined type and you don't provide a postfix version, the compiler (in Visual C++ at least) will use the PREFIX version when your code calls the missing POSTFIX version.

At least it will give you a warning. But, my question is: Why doesn't it just give you an error for the undefined member function?

I have seen this first hand, and have seen it mentioned in another post and elsewhere, but I cannot find this in the actual C++ standard.  My second and third questions are... Is it in the standard somewhere?  Is this a Microsoft-specific handing of the situation?

Comment: @Arbalest: Actually VC++ has been much better with C++ standards conformance with their newer versions. And the OP did get warnings when MS extensions are used, so it's not like the compiler is doing this behind the OP's back. You should be able to compile cleanly with `/W4 /WX` (warning level 4 + turn warnings into errors).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, In this case the MSVC behaves much more intelligently than GCC.
This is a MSVC compiler extension and the C++ standard explicitly allows for such an behavior.

C++ Standard:
**Section 1.4/8:**
*A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any well-formed program. **Implementations are required to diagnose programs that use such extensions that are ill-formed according to this International Standard. Having done so, however, they can compile and execute such programs.***

In this case, MSVC appropriately diagnoses the problem that the postfix is not available and it specifically defines warnings,
**[Compiler Warning (level 1) C4620](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12waye2f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**
**[Compiler Warning (level 1) C4621](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkt91exs.aspx)**

Also, it provides you a facility to disable the MSVC specific extensions by using **[/Za](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx)**. Overall, I would say this is one of the instances where MSVC actually behaves better than GCC.

Comment: Given the ease of defining some operators from others (typically >, >= and <= from <), I would welcome such an extension in other compilers :)

Comment: @Matthieu M.: in the absence of such extension, you can always use [boost::operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/utility/operators.htm)!

Comment: @Luc: I have, unfortunately the resulting dumps in gdb are nigh unreadable because of the bloat it creates. I haven't yet figured out how to tell gdb *not* to expand those particular bases. At that point, my best solution is to provide a set of macros that define the supplementary methods (inline).

Comment: @Als - interesting. I was looking for pre/postfix verbiage in the standard to see if this was a defined behavior.  The clause you reference casts a pretty wide net. And if you didn't stumble on it how would one ever know?  I'll be using /Za for now on.

Comment: @Arbalest: That's true, And Yes I had to do fair bit of research to arrive at an answer which would convince myself as well. That done with, Finally, I was staring at the same question which you ask now, And yes the answer was to use `/Za` and that is the reason I added that part to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a Microsoft specific extension. Because, at least g++ is strict about prefix and postfix operators. Here is the [demo link](http://www.ideone.com/aK6r7).

Answer (score -1):

With integers, ++i is different from i++. For exampe i=5, y = ++i - y will be 6; y=i++ - y will be 5. Other types should function in the same manner. Therefore the behaviour differs between postfix and prefix.

It is a Microsoft thing and in my opinion the compilers implementation is incorrect.

Comment: Didn't Downvote, But your answer is incorrect, It is perfectly within the behaviors allowed by the standard. Check my answer for detail.